# Relationship between the velocity of a photoelectron and the current it creates when received by a plate?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electricity, photoelectric-effect

I was studying the photoelectric effect and came across the following doubt. In a circuit that consists of a battery, a set of two plates and an ammeter; energetic enough light is shone on to the positive plate such that it emits photoelectrons. I understand that the maximum kinetic energy of the photoelectrons is given by the formula:

> $KE = \frac{1}{2}mv^2 =hf - Φ$

This implies that the electron is ejected with a velocity of:

> $v = \sqrt{\frac{2(hf - Φ)}{m}}$

However the electron is emitted from the positive plate and into the negative which means it travels against the voltage of the circuit and so I assume it must loose momentum.

My question goes to wether it is possible to calculate the velocity with which the electron hits the negative plate. However I do not want to use the equation $W = qV$, I want to use the current that is detected when the photoelectrons are received at the negative plate, I know there must be a relationship because when I increase the frequency of light (, increase ejection speed of the photoelectron,) the current in the circuit increases aswell.

Please if anybody knows how exactly the 'arrival' velocity of the photoelectron relates to the current in the circuit it would be of great help. Thank you!